# How to use custom blocks with bookdown in PDF

Tags: r, latex, bookdown

I am trying to create custom background colors for blocks of text in a book chapter.  If I add this code:

````
```{block, type="FOO"}
blah
```
````

to my Rmd file and this:

```
div.FOO {
   font-weight: bold;
   background-color: LightGray;
}
```

to my style.css file the html page looks great but the PDF output no longer includes the chapter and the table of contents is missing.

Can someone please tell me what to tweak to get a PDF to use a custom block?  Unfortunately I don't speak TeX so clues for the clueless would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "output no longer includes the **chapter**";. Did you mean to say **chunk**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give your some context for my answer, [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Learn_LaTeX_in_30_minutes) is a "Learn LaTeX in 30 Minutes" talk. It's probably worth your time to take a look at it, just so that you understand more of the basic environment syntax.

To answer your question, `bookdown` projects have a file called `preamble.tex`. I believe you should add the following lines to that file:

```
\newenvironment{Foo}{
  \begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{|p{0.9\textwidth}|}
  \hline  \\
}

{
  \\\\\hline
  \end{tabular} 
  \end{center}
}
```

I'm not sure if that answers all of your question, but that's what I have so far.

Comment: fyi if I include the blank line in the middle of this block it generates an error ("! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.") which I remove by omitting this blank line

Answer (score 1):

You should review [Section 9.6 in the R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/custom-blocks.html) (Xie, Dervieux, and Riederer 2020) for instructions.

In short, you need a `preamble.tex` file containing the LaTeX commands for making your custom block (with which you will try and mimic the CSS which defines how it looks in HTML)

You will also need to markup custom blocks in your `.Rmd` file differently, like this

```
:::: {FOO}
blah
::::
```